# How to initialize a Property from one struct in an other struct

Tags: swiftui

I was looking for some Code (SwiftUI) to get a JSON File from a website into my Xcode Project, and I found a good Sample but when I try to change the Code and wanna use a 'var' from one struct in an other struct.

```
struct Course: Decodable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    var link: String
    let imageUrl: String
    let number_of_lessons: Int
}

class NetworkManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var courses = [Course]()

    func getAllCourses() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/jsondecodable/courses") else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            do {
                let courses = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course].self, from: data!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.courses = courses
                    print(courses)
                }
            } catch {
                print("Failed To decode: ", error)
            }
        }.resume()
    }

    init() {
        getAllCourses()
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var cs:Course
    var body: some View {
        Text(cs.name)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView() //here it says Missing argument for parameter...
    }
```

Xcode says:  Missing argument for parameter 'cs' in call, Insert 'cs:<#Course#>'.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to initialize a struct, you need to pass all properties with setters, here that is `cs`, as `body` is a get-only property.

You will need to pass a `Course` object via `SwiftUIView(cs: course)`. This course can be just a static course, as it's only used in your SwiftUI preview.

Comment: Ok, I'm not quite sure if I understood you correctly,  I tried to do initialize it, but I only got the error for SwiftUIView(cs: course) Use of unresolved identifier 'course'. When I try SwiftUIView(cs: Course) it says: Cannot convert value of type 'Course.Type' to expected argument type 'Course'

Comment: You will need to add all properties to initialise the struct, so `Course(id: 1, name: “test”, link: “test”, imageUrl: “test”, number_of_sessions: 1)`. This will make a new instance of this struct. Please read the Swift book on initialisation, it’s all described there.

Answer (score 0):

Swift autogenerates initializers for structs, so your SwiftUIView has one like this:

```
public init(cs: Course) {
    self.cs = cs
}
```

So in order to create an instance of your SwiftUIView in the previews you have to declare it like this:

```
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static let cs = Course(id: 7,
                           name: "The best course",
                           link: "thebestcourse.com",
                           imageUrl: "thebestcourse.com/image.jpg",
                           number_of_lessons: 5)

    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView(cs: cs)
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your way, but now I have the problem that I only get the values from the static let declaration and if I want to call the SwiftUIView in the ContentView (my main View) i´ll get the error Missing argument for parameter 'cs' in call, Insert 'cs:<#Course#>'.

Comment: You need static in front of the declaration for previews to work. Don’t use inside actual views. Maybe include your ContentView code as well.